# Karate Mock Test Doubles not recognizing the headerContains scenario parameter

Tags: mocking, http-headers, karate

This is not a question about a simple Karate test feature file. This is a mock feature file!
I really need to be checking for the Authorization token in my mock feature file. Everything else is working as long as I don't use the `headerContains` param. With it, I get an error.
I have also tried `requestHeaders.val[0]`, I get the same issue.
Also, I tried to find a way to log the content of the header but there seems to be no way to do that in the mock feature file.
Using `karate.log` doesn't log any of that request information.
Here is the error I get with the `headerContains` in the JavaScript scenario description:

> 17:07:14.285 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] WARN  com.intuit.karate - scenario match evaluation failed: javascript evaluation failed: pathMatches('/v1/oauth2/accesstoken') && paramValue('grant_type') == 'client_credentials' && methodIs('get') && headerContains('Authorization', 'Basic blablablatoken'), ReferenceError: "headerContains" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1

And this is the message without it:

> 17:17:11.787 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - scenario matched: pathMatches('/v1/oauth2/accesstoken') && paramValue('grant_type') == 'client_credentials' && methodIs('get')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies - the documentation has a mistake and `headerContains()` actually does not exist. The docs are updated in [`develop`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-netty)

Can you use `karate.get()` like this:

```
Scenario: karate.get('requestHeaders.Authorization[0]') == 'expected'
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you so much for such a quick response. This worked perfectly. Again, thank you!!!

Comment: @IsabelleT. no problem. I actually feel `headerContains()` makes sense, so will see if can be added in the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/997

Comment: I have a follow up question. On the second scenario, I need to verify the token passed is the one created during the first scenario. I have tried passing it like: karate.get('requestHeaders.Authorization[0]') == '#(token)' or like karate.get('requestHeaders.Authorization[0]') == token, but the token doesn't get replaced by its value. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @IsabelleT. each `Scenario` is very independent. you can try to modify a "global" variable you init in the `Background` and no, the `#(foo)` embedded expression approach does *not* work for plain JS - ask another separate question if needed to be clear